# URL Rewrite Issue with Mango Blog (404 error)

Tags: mod-rewrite, coldfusion, apache2

I am working on setting up an instance of Mango Blog on an Ubuntu Server running Apache 2 HTTPD and Tomcat 6 with Railo 3.1.2.  I was able to get everything setup until I started trying to implement URL rewriting for the blog URLs.

I used a combination of [Adam Tuttle's](http://fusiongrokker.com/post/even-prettier-ses-urls-in-mango) and [John Sieber's](http://www.john-sieber.com/post/mango-url-rewriting) posts to get the rewrite rules.  I have the site setup as follows:

{webroot}/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
# archives rule must be located before page rule for paging to work correctly
RewriteRule archives/(.*)$              archives.cfm/$1 [PT,L,NC]
RewriteRule page/(.*)$                  page.cfm/$1 [PT,L,NC]
RewriteRule post/(.*)$                  post.cfm/$1 [PT,L,NC]
RewriteRule author/(.*)$                author.cfm/$1 [PT,L,NC]
```

{apache-home}/sites-enabled/sitename

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin *******

        DocumentRoot /var/www/******/www
        ServerName mango.*****.com
        DirectoryIndex index.cfm

        <Directory /var/www/*******.com/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride all
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error-*******_com.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access-********_com.log combined

        ProxyPreserveHost Off
        ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.cf[cm])(/.*)?$ ajp://********.com:8009/

</VirtualHost>
```

When I visit blog posts by going to /post/hello-world on the site I get a 404 error.  If I go to /post.cfm/hello-world the post comes up just fine.  I tried the rewrite rules against a [rewrite tester](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/), and that said that the rewrites should work fine.  I am very new to rewriting, so I apologize if this is something simple.

Comment: For me Mango URL rewriting is a black magic, and I'm having new problems for each new installation...

Comment: In theory it shouldn't be too hard.  It is really just removing .cfm from the URLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put in your .htaccess file:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer akond.  Would you mind explaining a little bit more about why that option fixes the problem?

Comment: Ay, sure. This directive turns negotiation off. For more information visit http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html and look for "Multiviews".

Comment: @akond I don't see why he had Mutiviews at the server level either  ... :: Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your rewrite rules to the VirtualHost block. I've had weird problems with .htaccess not working correctly w/ rewrites.

I could be wrong here, but this is what I think happens.

Apache is going to look for /post/, which doesn't exist and return the 404. It'd run .htaccess if it existed in /post/, but it doesn't.

If the rewrite rules are in your Directory block inside the VirtualHost block in httpd.conf file, then Apache knows to redirect instead of looking for /post/.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin *******

    DocumentRoot /var/www/******/www
    ServerName mango.*****.com
    DirectoryIndex index.cfm

    <Directory /var/www/*******.com/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride all
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all

            RewriteEngine on
            RewriteBase /
            # archives rule must be located before page rule for paging to work correctly
            RewriteRule archives/(.*)$              archives.cfm/$1 [PT,L,NC]
            RewriteRule page/(.*)$                  page.cfm/$1 [PT,L,NC]
            RewriteRule post/(.*)$                  post.cfm/$1 [PT,L,NC]
            RewriteRule author/(.*)$                author.cfm/$1 [PT,L,NC]
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error-*******_com.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access-********_com.log combined

    ProxyPreserveHost Off
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.cf[cm])(/.*)?$ ajp://********.com:8009/
```

Comment: When I add my rewrites at the end of my VirtualHost config it first gives me an error the `RewriteBase: only valid in per-directory config files`, and when I comment it out I now get a 400 error when I try to visit a rewritten url like /post/hello-world

Comment: Move the rewrite rule code inside the <Directory> #moveHere </Directory>. Updated original w/ new code.

Comment: I still get the 404 error when I move the rewrites into the directory tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be related to your RewriteBase.  When I loaded your example onto a test server, I saw in Apache's error logs that using the RewriteBase was working for me because of the environment I was using; however, using / in your case might not be creating the correct path.

In your web server error logs, see what path is being generated when it says it can't find the 404 error.  Likely, it will say something like:

```
[21/May/2011:17:29:20 +0000] [error] [client #.#.#.#] File does not exist: /path/to/something/not/quite/right/post.cfm/hello_world
```

Follow the path to make sure it's actually leading you to the actual server location where the *.cfm files reside.  Then just modify your RewriteBase to make it the right path.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The only error that looks like it is related to the rewrite is `Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /var/www/******/www/post (None could be negotiated)`

Comment: This is definitely related to the problem you're having. That's a new error for me, but perhaps it's related to mod_negotiation and the file handle types it's looking for?  Maybe try disabling mod_negotiation (if it's even enabled for your web server) to see if it affects the nature of the error.

Comment: This is most certainly a mod_negotiation related problem.